# How to use maven archtype:generate with local archetype?

Tags: java, maven

I have a local defined archetype. The problem is that this localy defined archetype is not listed, when i call mvn archetype:generate.
What must i do to enable maven to use my own archetype?

Comment: please add your locally defined archetype

Comment: have you used mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local

Comment: I have used mvn -o generate:archetype.

Comment: When i try mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local, then comes the following error: No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)

Answer (score 1):

execute it as

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local
```

also mention it properly like below:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook \
-DartifactId=simple \
-Dpackage=org.sonatype.mavenbook \
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```